# Msbuild - Output is moved intermittently because of Aestrik (*)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, msbuild-itemgroup

I am trying to build csproj using msbuild which stores output on the fly and then move it to configured output directory, Simple :). But values passed with aestrik (*) works intermittently however other value get moved always.

Snap of Required Code:-

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PublisherRunnables Include="$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)WebservicePublisher.exe" />
    <PublisherAssamblies Include="$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)*.dll" />
    <PublisherConfigs Include="$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)Configurations.xml" />

<Target Name="ReorganizeFiles" DependsOnTargets="CopyPackageOutput">
    <Move SourceFiles="@(PublisherRunnables)" DestinationFolder="c:\Builds\_tmp\" />
    <Move SourceFiles="@(PublisherAssamblies)" DestinationFolder="c:\Builds\_tmp\Libs" />
    <Move SourceFiles="@(PublisherConfigs)" DestinationFolder="c:\Builds\_tmp\" />
  </Target>
```

output - 
    First time i build project Results-

```
WebservicePublisher.exe
Configurations.xml
None of the dll's are moved
```

Second time i build project Results -

```
WebservicePublisher.exe
Configurations.xml
All required dll's are moved
```

Note - No issue with build order, if i specify specific dll rather than *.dll , it works every time.

Comment: How about the result when you build with Visual Studio? And I notice that your target ReorganizeFiles depends on target CopyPackageOutput, is this target executed after Build? Since we have your custom task CopyPackageOutput, I tested this question with <Target Name="ReorganizeFiles" AfterTargets="Build"> , it works fine with Visual Studio.

Comment: Same issue with visual Studio too - i have multiple targets such

Comment: </Target>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="Initialization" />
    <CallTarget Targets="BuildPackage" />
    <CallTarget Targets="CopyPackageOutput" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="ReorganizeFiles" RunEachTargetSeparately="True" />
    <CallTarget Targets="PackCrmProxyService" />
    <CallTarget Targets="PackPublisher" />
  </Target>  - As is said before there is no issue with build order

Comment: Have you ever tried to clear the output folder every time after build? Like: Build the project first, then clean the output folder, build the project again.

Comment: Yes, in every build my Output folder gets clean .